# Which lesser known browsers are based on their OWN engine?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I wanted to test some sites in some lesser known browsers. So I downloaded Comodo and SeaMonkey. The former seems to be based off webkit and renders just like Chrome, the latter seems to be based off Firefox.

Are any of the lesser known browsers based on their own engine? It shouldn't be too unknown (I don't care about the really obscure ones), something along the lines of Comodo and SeaMonkey in popularity but with it's own render engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia might be helpful here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers

Or special browsers here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Current

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison of web browser engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines)